# How to get branch name in a Github Action Shell script

Tags: yaml, github-actions

I'm trying to create an output to use later in the job.

However, for some reason, the `BRANCH` env variable which I'm getting to be the `GITHUB_REF_NAME` is an empty string, which [according to the docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables), should be the branch.

Also using the variable directly produces the same result.

```
      - name: Set Terraform Environment Variable
        id: set_tf_env
        env:
          BRANCH: ${{env.GITHUB_REF_NAME}}
        run: |
          if [ "$BRANCH" == "dev" ]; then
              run: echo "::set-output name=TF_ENV::dev"
              elif [ "$BRANCH" == "prod" ]; then
              run: echo "::set-output name=TF_ENV::prod"
          else
              echo "Branch has no environment"
              exit 1
          fi
```

Comment: There is a context variable in github actions that you can use to get the branch name: `github.ref`. For example, for the `dev` branch, you could use a conditionnal at a step level like this: `if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/dev`

Comment: Did you try to actually print out this variable? If I remember correctly it starts with refs/heads so likely your comparison is not correct, but the variable itself should not be empty.

Comment: @taleodor There's also `github.ref_name`.

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at this doc, I think it's pretty well explained: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So after a bit of more research and thanks to the comments, I discovered the reason why it wasn't working.

It was because I was triggering a GitHub action in a Pull Request, something I failed to mention.

So what I ended up using was:

```
github.event.pull_request.head.ref
```